# Can you answer this question?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

I have below lines, and Guess what can be the answer ?

```
    Sir, I bear a rhyme excelling
    In mystic force and magic spelling
    Celestial sprites elucidate
    All my own striving can't relate
```

What is your answer ?

> Hint : William Jones

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ngn, I have updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-known poem where

> the lengths of the words are the digits of pi, in order.

The hint's relevance:

> William Jones was the first to use the "π" symbol to refer to the ratio between the circumference and diameter of a circle.